# slither: KeyError: 2394, 2863

Tags: solidity, slither

When I try to run `slither .` inside my contracts folder (hardhat project), I get this super weird warning

```
...python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 291, in get_line_from_offset
    return lines_delimiters[offset]
KeyError: 2394
None
Error in .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem hopefully, as it did for me. (inspired by this, even though different error https://github.com/crytic/slither/issues/103)

1. delete `artifacts` and `cache` folders created by `npx hardhat compile`
2. run a fresh `npx hardhat compile`
3. run `slither .` => works

If you know the reason behind this error, please add your answer.